# difference in id selector and namespace in less

Tags: css, less

I am trying to learn less to reduce the pain of repetitive css. One thing that confuses me is the syntax of namespace in less. To my understanding, less is compatible with css, therefore

```
#myelement-id{}
```

is an id selector.  On the other hand, less supports namespace by specifying

```
#namespace{}
```

So, when I read a less file, how can I tell which "#" is for id selector and which is for namespace?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have never used less, but I guess from your question that the -id part might be the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference. A `#id` or `.class` can be used as a namespace call to access its other classes or mixins. To make it different, you need to make it a mixin. So either of these is valid:

```
#namespace {
  .test {
    prop: 1;
  }
}

#namespace() {
  .test {
    prop: 1;
  }
}
```

The first will produce css output as an `id` selector, the second will not. But either can access the nested values, so either of these work inside a selector block to access the `.test` class via this:

```
.class {
  #namespace > .test;
}
```

But the output will be different, as the first will be:

```
#namespace .test {
  prop: 1;
}
.class {
  prop: 1;
}
```

And the second just:

```
.class {
  prop: 1;
}
```

Comment: A small correction, this: `#namespace() > .test;` does not actually work in LESS. A member of parametric namespace can be accessed either like this: `#namespace(); .test;` or like this: `#namespace > .test;`

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That's what I get for answering near midnight :-). I've corrected the answer (and had even tested that before posting, but then forgot to properly write it out). However, a clarification to your correction should be noted. The `#namespace(); .test;` will result in different output also, similar to the first output, only it will be `.class .test { prop: 1}` for the additional selector. Also, that would not technically be accessing the namespace _as a namespace_, but rather evoking it as a mixin, followed by then evoking its output child class `.test` as a mixin.

Comment: Yep, `#namespace(); .test;` is like expanding namespace into current scope... similar to `using namespace xxx;` in some mainstream languages :-).

Answer (score 1):

More over, there's no difference even between a mixin and a namespace. A namespace can also be parametric (though parametric namespaces have some unusual properties/side-effects that make them differ from non-parametric namespaces). See for example [#1205](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1205), [#1316](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1316), [#1525](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1525).

Basically, LESS namespace is just any ruleset that contains another ruleset(s). It's more like a logical concept/convention, not a language construction.